# Is it possible to connect to a remote database on an ec2 instance with php pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm using the following to connect to a mysql database from the localhost

```
<?php
function testdb_connect ()
{
   $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "testuser", "testpass");
   return ($dbh);
}
?>
```

However when I tried to connect to this database (database is running on `ec2-12-34-56-78.compute-1.amazonaws.com`) from a different server, using the following code

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=ec2-12-34-56-78.compute-1.amazonaws.com;dbname=test", "testuser", "testpass");
```

I'm unable to connect.

Is it possible to connect to a remote database on an ec2 instance with php pdo?

How would I pass an authentication parameter (ex. private key)

Comment: It's entirely possible, but you'll need your security groups in order.

Comment: Can you please discuss how you security groups are configured.  This is likely problem.  What kind of error are you getting on the attempted connection?

Comment: It's not really up to PHP.  This is entirely a question of EC2 configuration.  If you can get EC2 to open the port up to the world, then you can connect to it.  Or you could just open up a SSH tunnel to the db port, and connect to the SSH tunnel instead.  Or set up some sort of VPN between your two locations.

Comment: I have 1 security group with ports 22 and 80 open with the database server and the other server that is to call the database.  How can I configure the security groups in order to allow the other server to access the database server?  *(I'll post the error I get on attempting a connection when I get back home)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably consider using RDS for your database rather than implementing on EC2 unless you have a very unique database that requires a high degree of customization (i.e. clustered configurations, etc.).  Running on EBS-backed volume (which you would need to do to be able to persist the physical data files), will subject you to slow disk I/O.  If you are not running on EBS-backed EC2, then your data is transient and can not be considered as being on reliable physical storage.  If this is OK for your design (you just need transient info in your database), then you would probably be even better served but just putting your information into Elasticache or some form of in-memory cache.

RDS uses MySQL (well, you can also opt to use Oracle).  You would access it EXACTLY like you would access your own MySQL server (same PHP abstraction, same SQL, same almost everything (you don't get root access, but rather a form of super-user access).  RDS also provide you easy to implement (i.e. push button) configuration for multi-az (high-availability, synchronously-updated standby), replication slaves, DB instance re-sizing, and data snapshots.

In either case (for RDS or EC2), you would need to make sure that your EC2 or RDS security groups allows access from the EC2 instances (or other servers) that host your application.  In case of EC2 only you could either place the servers in the same security group, and provide port 3306 access on that group, or better would be to create two security groups (one for app and one for db). In the db security group provide port 3306 (or whatever port you are using) to the security group(s) to which the app server(s) belong.

For an RDS, you would need EC2 security group for app server(s) and a DB security group for the RDS instance).  You would need to provide access to the app server security group in the RDS security config.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I will look into it.  Can you advise me on how to configure my security groups if I wanted to stick with mysql?

Comment: Thanks Mike - I'll check this out when I get home.

Comment: Mike can you comment on benjobradley's suggestion of creating a tunnel to the database server?  What are the pluses and minuses of this approach?

Comment: @user784637 I have not done a configuration like that when using Amazon.  For RDS you can read more here about SSL-encrypted connections:  http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#53   For EC2, obviously you would need to implement this yourself (certs, SSH, server, security group config, etc.).  I think the general thought is that DB connections over SSL will impact connection performance, so should only be used for those specific cases where the data being transferred warrants such additional security measures (above and beyond the security group configs).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the specifics of how this might work with AWS but the first thing I would do is get an SSH tunnel running between the machines.

Then PHP/PDO would basically just think that you're connecting to a local database. In my experience it also makes the connection faster to establish as it doesn't have to do a DNS lookup to find the remote server... quite a big deal when you think that every PHP page load might have to connect to the remote DB.

I use this on intranets when an application needs to manage data stored on a remote database and it works like a champ.

I find SSH tunnels perfectly stable but I use a program called [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) to attempt to reconnect SSH tunnels when they go down.

For completeness here's the command I use to start autossh so it establishes and maintains a particular SSH tunnel. Added here because I found the autossh docs pretty confusing to work out what options I wanted.

```
autossh -M 0 -f -L3307:127.0.0.1:3306 -p 22 -N -f username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

This forwards port 3307 on your web server to 3306 on the remote DB server. So in PHP you would connect to 3307. You could choose 3306 if you wanted, I chose local port 3307 just in case you had a local MySQL as well as a remote. The -p switch is the port that SSH is running on on the remote machine.

You can add this command to `/etc/rc.local` (on CentOS at least) to establish the SSH tunnel on server start.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thx you loathsome, offensive brute

Comment: Your icon is a portrait of the **The Kramer** which elicited the response *He's a loathsome, offensive brute* from the art connoisseurs in that episode...